# How do you set the tablesorter default filter type

Tags: tablesorter

I have a tablesorter table with titles in the cells. I'd like to be able to search on multiple, non-contiguous words in the title. The fuzzy match (~) does the job. How do I get this to be the default matcher? I don't want my users to have learn/remember it.

I tried a custom filter like this

```
....
widgetOptions: {
    filter_external: '.search', // input box that user input goes into
    filter_columnFilters: false,
    filter_functions : {
         1: function (e, n, f, i, $r) {
               return this.filter.types.fuzzy( e, '~' + n, f, i, $r);
            }
    }
}
.....
```

but that didn't work. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a new filter widget option `filter_defaultFilter` in the working branch of the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/tree/working)

To use it, include the column class name or index and a filter mask with the filter selector (`~` in your case) and a query tag (`{query}` or `{q}`).

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_defaultFilter: {
                // set default fuzzy match on first column
                0 : '~{q}'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/aLxsen8t/37/) applying a default exact match to filter selects for [issue #704](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/704#issuecomment-53755401).

The documentation is available now in the working branch. The [main documentation](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-defaultfilter) won't be updated until this weekend.